# HTML Parsing Error: Unable to modify the parent container element before the child element is closed (KB927917)

Tags: html, html-parsing

While running my wordpress website on IE 8 I got the status message as follows

"Done,But with errors on page".When clicking on that message I got the details like

```
`Webpage error details


Message: HTML Parsing Error: Unable to modify the parent container element before the child element is closed (KB927917)
Line: 0
Char: 0
Code: 0
URI: http://mywebsite.com/~stbruno/about-us/mission/

`
```

Why this happens.I googled for the solution and I couldn`t figure out any solution for my problem.Please help me

Comment: Try to move any script actions so that they only run once the DOM document is fully built, e.g. in an "onload" handler.

Comment: I didn`t get you.Could you please explain it bit more detail

Comment: You should create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and add it to your question. Then we'll have something concrete to discuss.